# Loop through String array for string with number, and pop it out and then split that into two variables?

Tags: apex

I have a `list<string>` that contains a list of elements like this

`element_a, element_b, element_c, element_d`

and that is easy enough to deal with,

```
 for(String elements : ELEMENTS_ARRAY) {   }
```

but I on occasion have a `list<string>` like this

```
element_a, element_b 3, element_c, element_d
```

I am trying to figure how how to deal with an array where a value contains a space followed by a number and then return the element_b with the number as two separate values.

Comment: Apex methods only support a single return value. Can you break down your use case for us with some more specifics as to what you need?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd start by looking at the available [String methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm). Seems like the various `substring[Before|After|Between]()` methods, `split()`, and/or `isNumeric()` could be applicable to your problem.

Comment: Currently looking into using a regular expression to find the value, but and looked into isNumeric, but that didn't work as the string itself would be alphanumberic

Comment: It's be used in a for loop to generate part of a soap request, but I need it to split the string with the number into a separate quantity field

Comment: did you checked -splitByCharacterType()?

Comment: splitByCharacterType, could potentially break due to case

Comment: I am looking along the line of

String regex = /( [\d])/g

if string contains regex
value_1 = number
value_2 = element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, Integer> tempMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
for(String element : ELEMENTS_ARRAY) {  
      if(element.contains(’ ’){
           tempMap.put(element.split(’ ’).get(0), Integer.valueOf(element.split(’ ’).get(1));
      }
 }
```

Then return the map and use the key as the element and its value as the number

Comment: That's perfect and works so cleanly